# How to address variable number of arguments in laravel routes to controllers

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I did something like this for my routes:

```
Route::get('/fundraisers/{id}', 'FundraiserController@index')->name('fundraisers.list');
Route::get('/{locale}/fundraisers/{id}', 'FundraiserController@indexLang')->name('fundraisers.list.lang')->where(['locale'=>$loc=['fr,'zh']);
```

And then I need two methods in my controller:

```
index($id) {
   // Load record by id and language == 'en'
}

indexLang($locale, $id) {
   // Load record by id and language == $locale
}
```

I read elsewhere that there's no way around explicitly writing two route rules if I want English urls to be the only exception to not appearing in the url.

Now when I write a route like this:

```
Route::get('/fundraisers/{id}', 'FundraiserController@indexLang')->name('fundraisers.list');
```

What happens is that `$locale` is a number and `$id` is null in `indexLang`.  Is there a way to do something like assign `{id}` to a `$_REQUEST['id']` and have `$_REQUEST['locale']` be unset?  Like the way you would have it with `.htaccess` url rewrite rules?  That way I can get rid of `index($id)` since it's redundant exception of `indexLang`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your first attempt, except for the `where` which needs to be a regular expression.

`Route::get('/{locale}/fundraisers/{id}', 'FundraiserController@indexLang')->name('fundraisers.list.lang')->where(['locale' => 'fr|zh']);`

So try that.

The reason in the second attempt for "`$locale` is a number and `$id` is null" is because you're only capturing one in the route i.e. `'/fundraisers/{id}'` which is then being passed to the controller's first variable, in this case `$locale`.